# OnTouchListener stops working after starting a new Activity

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I'm making a simple a game in Android. Basically, I want it to operate this way: When the app is started, a playing screen will appear and when a collision between player and an obstacle is detected, the game will stop and an AlertDialog will appear. The player then click the button "Replay" and a playing screen will appear again. An OnTouch method is needed to make player jump.
And everything seems to work just fine, except one thing: The OnTouch method works well when the app is started, but it stops working after I clicked the "Replay" button. The thing is that a new playing screen appears, and everything moves just as I programmed, only the OnTouch method doesn't work.
This is my code for the MainActivity class and the GamePanel class:

MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    GamePanel gp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        gp = new GamePanel(this);
        gp.setOnTouchListener(this);
        setContentView(gp);
        gp.start();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {;
        gp.pl.setUp(true);
        gp.pl.setClickup(true);

        return true;
    }


}
```

GamePanel.java

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
    Thread t;
    SurfaceHolder s;
    Paint p;
    Player pl;
    ArrayList<Tube>tubes;
    MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
    Context c;

    public GamePanel(Context context){

        super(context);
        s = getHolder();
        pl = new Player();
        p = new Paint();
        tubes = new ArrayList<>();
        Tube newTube = new Tube(300, 600,300);
        tubes.add(newTube);
        addTube();
        c = context;

    }

    public void addTube(){
        while(tubes.size()<=4){
            Tube LastTube = tubes.get(tubes.size()-1);
            Random r = new Random();
            float yBelow = r.nextInt(450)+300;
            float Gap = r.nextInt(300)+150;
            Tube newTube;
            if(yBelow<Gap+20){
                yBelow = yBelow + (Gap - yBelow) + 150;
                newTube = new Tube(LastTube.getxAbove()+200, yBelow, Gap);
            }
            else {
                newTube = new Tube(LastTube.getxAbove()+200, yBelow, Gap);
            }
            tubes.add(newTube);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true){
            if(!s.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }
            Canvas c = s.lockCanvas();
            pl.move();
            for(Tube t: tubes){
                t.move();
                t.replace();
            }
            c.drawARGB(255,199,222,100);
            p.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            c.drawCircle(pl.getX(),pl.getY(),20,p);
            for(Tube t: tubes){
                c.drawRect(t.getxAbove(),t.getyAbove(),t.getxAbove()+Tube.getWidth(),t.getyBelow()-t.getGap(),p);
                c.drawRect(t.getxBelow(),t.getyBelow(),t.getxBelow()+Tube.getWidth(),c.getHeight(),p);
            }
            for(Tube t: tubes){
                if(t.checkCollision(pl,c)){
                    restart();
                }
            }
            getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public void restart(){
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        AlertDialog.Builder box = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
                        box.setMessage("You Lost");
                        box.setCancelable(true);
                        box.setPositiveButton("Replay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(c,MainActivity.class);
                                c.startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog dialog = box.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                });

        try {
           t.join();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void start(){

        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

}
```

Please help me fix it. 
Ps: I've just found out that after I restart the game, not only the onTouchListener stops working but also the AlertDialog stops appearing when I lose. And later a dialog shows up, telling me "Test isn't responding", although both "player" object and "tube" objects still move as programmed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `android:launchMode="singleTask"`

According to documentation:

> The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.

So you have 2 options:

1. Create a new method and move the functions which needs to be initialized again in the new method and call that method in onCreate() and onNewIntent().
2. In intent, use intent flags ( i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); )

I hope it helps.

Comment: No, my launchMode is default,. And even when I changed it to singleTask and do as you suggested, the problem was still there.

Comment: onNewIntent and intent flags didnt help?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. Btw, I've just found out that after I restart the game, not only the onTouchListener stops working but also the AlertDialog stops appearing when I lose. And later a dialog shows up, telling me "Test isn't responding". If you know why please help me.

Comment: Weird. Can you update your question with latest changes in project? Add AndroidManifest.xml too

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your onTouchListener in onResume method instead that in onCreate, cause onResume is called after Dialog is destroyed and the control returns to your Activity.